# Where are the Type annotation constraints (`ValueRange`/`MinLen` etc) in python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

After seeing the (awesome) new `Annotated` type annotation in python 3.9 (varaidic type constraints!), I rushed to upgrade so I could check them out.
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=valuerange)

But when I tried using `ValueRange[min,max]` or `MaxLen[n]` - I couldn't seem to find them anywhere..
PyCharm didn't offer me any help, and they don't seem to be in the `typing` module where I might expect them.

The docs feature them but googling I can't find any reference online as to how to actually *import* them.

Are they not in the language yet? or just in some new module I'm not aware of?

Comment: Is ValueRange not just an example? It only appears in that context, it's not documented in its own right.

Comment: You might be right. I couldn't find any example declaration so assumed it was something in the stdlib. So the constraints are dynamic? If so how would I go about declaring those on my own?

Alternatively, how could I annotate constraints to the size/values of a list in some other way?

Comment: The point of the example is that it's *not* defined, the second parameter is metadata and ignored in the absence of specific logic.

Comment: Well gee, I got excited too.  It would be cool to see an example of a ValueRange implementation.

Comment: A full example solution has been posted in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454202/how-to-use-maxlen-of-typing-annotation-of-python-3-9/68489244#68489244).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use MaxLen of typing.Annotation of python 3.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454202/how-to-use-maxlen-of-typing-annotation-of-python-3-9)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, these classes are just an example of what can be annotated. Annotation just grabs a certain variable and adds some "hints" to them via the class you created (MaxLen, ValueRange, etc).

You can then obtain which "hints" are related to every parameter using `get_type_hints`, and crawl one per one the parameters with its hits and do the checks you want (not the idea Annotation was intended, though I also found it interesting). You have a [full example in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454202/how-to-use-maxlen-of-typing-annotation-of-python-3-9/68489244#68489244).

Answer (score 1):

You could define it using `dataclasses.dataclass`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ValueRange:
    min: float
    max: float
```

or alternatively using `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

ValueRange = namedtuple("ValueRange", ["min", "max"])
```